# Instagram URL --> JSON

Tags: php, json, instagram

How can I go about convering a public instagram URL into JSON using PHP?  Ex: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/brindle/

I can't use the API as I need public hashtag content and my use case won't qualify for their app review process :-(.

Here is what I have so far but it does not pull all images.  Also, I'd like to be able to load the "load more" images as well.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
$instagram_source = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/brindle/");
$instagram_data = explode("window._sharedData = ", $instagram_source);
$instagram_json = explode(';</script>', $instagram_data[1]);
$instagram_array = json_decode($instagram_json[0], TRUE);

$instagram_media = $instagram_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['tag']['media']['nodes'];
if(!empty($instagram_media)) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach($instagram_media as $im) {
echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/'.$im['code'].'/" target="_blank">';
        echo '<img src="'.$im["display_src"].'" alt="" width="'.$im["dimensions"]["width"].'" height="'.$im["dimensions"]["height"].'" />';
    echo '</a>';
echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: You'll need to somehow emulate browser actions to trigger those images to load up before you parse.  If you're familiar with javascript I think there are some nodejs browser testing options available that may work.  This one comes to mind: http://nightwatchjs.org/

Comment: If you're not using their API, then what you're basically doing is screen-scraping the HTML. Bear in mind that (a) some sites have T&Cs that prohibit this (not sure about Instagram, but do check!), and (b) that the site may change their HTML layout without warning, and it will break your script. If you do decide to do screen scraping, I suggest using a library like [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this solution here: https://github.com/Bolandish/Instagram-Grabber

Thats the best one i know until now.